# Phone charger power supply for raspberry pi 4

Tags: pi-4, power-supply

I have a Motorola power supply with output: 5v 3a 15w or 10v 2a 20w or 12v 1.67a 20w.  My question is: can I use this power supply for my raspberry?  Or is there a risk that it could be burned or damaged?  Does the power supply automatically give the raspberry the energy it needs?

Comment: if it's a correctly designed USB power supply, then it should provide 5 V at up to 500 mA ... any other voltages, and current levels, have to be negotiated by the device

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!

Comment: it is a comment, not an answer